# Initialize a float array on construction

Tags: c++

Is there a way in C++ to construct a float array initializing it's values?

For example, i do:

```
float* new_arr = new float[dimension];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i) new_arr[i] = 0;
```

Is it possible to do the assignment during the contruction?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
float* new_arr = new float[dimension]();
```

Comment: And with uniform initialization (C++11) you can do `new float[dimension]{}` or even give values: `new float[dimension]{1.f,.5f,1.3f}`.

Comment: If you are not using C++11 and want to do it, you can probably get away with declaring a static const array somewhere where you store the initial values, and memcpying it over your newly allocated arrays.

Comment: @Wug not `memcpy`, `std::copy`

Answer (score 11):

In this particular case (all zeroes) you can use value initialization:

```
float* new_arr = new float[dimension]();
```

Instead of explicitly using `new[]` you could use a [`std::vector<float>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<float> new_vec(dimension, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not free to use the vector template since i'm using some external lib. Thank you.

Comment: @Aslan986: if the problem is some function expection a `float*`, then simply pass `&v[0]`. a `std::vector` has guaranteed contiguous buffer. so unless you library is like, multi-processing on graphics card with custom runtime, then just use `std::vector`.